# Error creating bean with name 'discoveryRestTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Microservice application that I found in the web, but one of the microservices is causing problem and couldn't run. Here is the error stacktrace:

```html
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-08 02:26:05.537 ERROR 16596 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryRestTemplate': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "it.univaq.disim.discovery.common.property.DiscoveryStrategyProperties.getSelection()" because the return value of "it.univaq.disim.discovery.common.property.DiscoveryProperties.getStrategy()" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at it.univaq.disim.discovery.DiscoveryClientModuleApplication.main(DiscoveryClientModuleApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "it.univaq.disim.discovery.common.property.DiscoveryStrategyProperties.getSelection()" because the return value of "it.univaq.disim.discovery.common.property.DiscoveryProperties.getStrategy()" is null
    at it.univaq.disim.discovery.common.DiscoveryRestTemplate.setMlEngineService(DiscoveryRestTemplate.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:755) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

and this is an excerpt of the class where the problem occured :

```
@Slf4j
@Service
```

public class DiscoveryRestTemplate {

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryProperties discoveryProperties;

@Autowired
private Repository repository;

private SelectionService selectionService;

@Autowired
@DependsOn("discoveryProperties")
public void setMlEngineService(ApplicationContext context) {
    selectionService = (SelectionService) context.getBean(discoveryProperties.getStrategy().getSelection());
}
```

The DiscoveryProperties class looks like:

```
@Valid
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "discovery")
public class DiscoveryProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String context;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private DiscoveryAddressProperties address;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private DiscoveryStrategyProperties strategy;

    private Map<Integer, Double> delay;
    private Boolean register;

}
```

And this is the DiscoveryStrategyProperties class:

```
@Data

public class DiscoveryStrategyProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String selection;
    @NotNull
    private String prediction;

}
```

Comment: How do your `DiscoveryProperties` class looks like?

Comment: @HarryCoder  : I put it in the post, thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing some annotations:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigureProperties
public class DiscoveryStrategyProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String selection;
    @NotNull
    private String prediction;
}
```